# logstash mail to multiple recipients

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

at logstash conf filter , I assigned multiple email id to variable(variable name = targetmailid) and output field , I am trying to use that variable. However, it is assiging multiple email id's to CC field in output. Please suggest.

```
filter {
        kv {
                field_split => ","
                value_split=>":"

        }

        if [ref_type] =~ /tag/ {
                ruby {

                     code => "tag= event['ref']

                                 targetmailid = 'testuser1@mail.com,testuser2@mail.com,testuser3@mail.com' 

                              }
                    }
        }


        output {

        if "tagcreate" in [tags] {
                email {
                        body => "test messgage"
                        from => "admin@emil.com"
                        to => "admin2@email.com"
                        cc =>  "targetmailid"
                        subject => "test mail"
                        options => {
                            smtpIporHost => "smtp"
                            port => 25
                                   }
                                }
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the sprintf format `%{...}` like this:

```
email {
    body => "test messgage"
    from => "admin@emil.com"
    to => "admin2@email.com"
    cc =>  "%{targetmailid}"         <--- modify this
    subject => "test mail"
    options => {
        smtpIporHost => "smtp"
        port => 25
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Also make sure to modify the following part:

```
    if [ref_type] =~ /tag/ {
       ruby {
           code => "event['targetmailid'] = 'testuser1@mail.com,testuser2@mail.com,testuser3@mail.com'"
       }
    } else {
       mutate {
          add_field => { "targetmailid" => ""}
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error after modified like above and restarted logstash conf. 
Net::SMTPSyntaxError: 501 #5.1.3 Invalid character ('%') in username.Thank you

Comment: This means that the variable `targetmailid` is not available in all your events. You should add an `else` case where you create the `targetmailid` field (also note that your `ruby` filter is missing the `code => "..."` parameter) and add an empty `targetmailid` field if `ref_type` doesn't match `/tag/`

Comment: Hi, I edited the original question. I added targetmailid = 'testuser1@mail.com,testuser2@mail.com,testuser3@mail.com' under code=> only.  thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry . I added event like event['target'] = targetmailid. Now it is working fine. Thank you.